# How to check if an object implements the toString method at compile time?

Tags: typescript

I want to check if an object has the `toString` method implemented at compile time. However, since TypeScript considers all objects to inherit the `toString` method from the `Object`, straightforward approaches don't seem to work.

Consider the following scenario:

```
interface HasToString {
    toString(): string;
}

class A { }

const a: HasToString = new A(); // No compile-time error due to toString inheritance.
```

Is there a solution or pattern to achieve a compile-time type checking that ensures an object has the `toString` method properly implemented (not inherited from `Object`)?

In-runtime I checked it with:

```
function isValidToString(obj: unknown): obj is HasToString {
    return (
        typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null && typeof obj.toString === "function" && obj.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
    );
}
```

**UPDATED** See sample here most real: (I don't want to change the name of the method): [PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg0hEB5AZjcEA8MA0UBqAfFALxQDeAUFDVANoAKUAlgHZQDWiA9irALoBaAPwAuWI35QIAD2ARWAEwDOBKMKhNxrCADcIAJ0oBfOlxC8BAbkqU28gygCGAY2gAJJ8pjcAysAM2AHMKalpgPwDggAoASnFlKNYgm2NbFwAbL1VfJwBbMAyIAElFFgKivIVgVU9vSMDk0NooF25WRIMAVxcIg2iwQN0neRZFBKSg2PI0loj-RqC4qhaWgwhgLoN2YAALZmUAOmZFGxa0tMzsqABBZtpzcVyKktPbFraOgJ6%206JOJxbTMKrKB7A6HcykKA6ADuUGehVef0UsTOtAu6SyylUACF7jRHlAkAAjABWEF6NmBrXanR%203H6-ygnWCQJBNDBR0hZHIYygxjRNAxlCu2KgdV2NwMBicIGweAAotI5AoVLAEMg0Bh5czJlAAD7irw%20BbBQjEFa0T503oMgZDEbQPaIDWiBXTYXW4BQJziOomvVkWG3aIAcmJodRItp3uJUODOLDAGYAAwpyNUr3M-KIgCM8YgcIlUplcpueFD5lDhDDVajWeUOaKACYC0WvJLpbLMDiK1Wa5XEBmoAB6EdQABy3BpBWYRUEwGYVWk0oZUEUXSd0-merYu0MzGATlYbkOlCAA)

Comment: Why not just give your method a custom name if you don't want the default `toString()` anyway?

Comment: @VLAZ Obviously I need to use `toString` method to avoid changes in all classes with already implemented `toString`... I only want to exclude the default behavior for `toString` included in Object which prints `[object object]`. Otherwise, I would not ask it. I need it for a shared library. The idea is the developer detects classes with missing toString. The example is very simple, the real code involves type-checking more complex.

Comment: Right, so you need to define a custom method that converts an object to a string. If you're already doing that, why not give the method a custom name? There is no way in TS to check *where* a particular property is coming from. And right now what you essentially want is not "has a `toString()` but doesn't inherit it from `Object`" but rather "has a custom method that converts it to a string". And I'm not sure the value of trying to still keep to the default `toString()` if that's the case.

Comment: @VLAZ see a more real sample in the question updated. THanks

Comment: I still don't see anything there that ***requires*** you to use the default `toString()` as opposed to a custom method name.

Comment: @VLAZ because the KEYs in many cases are objects similar to `ObjectId` from Mongo which is an external library. In that case, we should change ALL ObjectId of the platform with a wrapper... I only want to know if it is possible to have a type-checking of this one, otherwise, we will go only with the runtime check.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "no this is not possible".  TypeScript's type system is *structural*, and `{toString(): string}` is the same structure regardless of where the implementation comes from.  Maybe there's some weird way to do it (e.g., modify the existing `interface Object {toString(): string}` type so that it returns a *supertype* of `string` and then you can tell whether something has overridden it) but even if it "works" it would be fighting against the type system and therefore likely to be fragile. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: There is [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43910) for this which did not receive a lot of attention. The suggestion was not very good though because it does not account for inheritance. A comment suggests using a [lint rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-base-to-string) that would simply make it impossible to call `toString` if it wasn't overridden. It would not work well for you if you are writing a library, but it could work well in a project maybe (just not very explicit)